# how to implement firebase in angular2seed advanced

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am using angular2seed-advanced from [github](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced).

I need to integrate firebase with my app. For that I follow this [documentation](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/wiki/How-to-integrate-Firebase-across-all-platforms-(web-nativescript-desktop)), unfortunately I couldn't integrate and got some errors.

Here I attach my files.

*main.web.ts*

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

// platfrom module
import { WebModule } from './web.module';
import { Config, DatabaseService } from './app/frameworks/core/index';
import { FIREBASE } from './app/frameworks/demoapp/index';
Config.PLATFORM_TARGET = Config.PLATFORMS.WEB;
Config.DEBUG.LEVEL_4 = true;

// app
import { WindowService, ConsoleService } from './app/frameworks/core/index';
import { CoreModule } from './app/frameworks/core/core.module';
import { ANALYTICS_PROVIDERS } from './app/frameworks/analytics/index';
import { MultilingualService } from './app/frameworks/i18n/index';
import { AppConfig } from './app/frameworks/sample/services/app-config';
import { SampleModule } from './app/frameworks/sample/sample.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app/components/app.component';

MultilingualService.SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = AppConfig.SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES;

declare var require: any
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/auth");
require("firebase/database");


if (String('<%= ENV %>') === 'prod' || String('<%= TARGET_DESKTOP_BUILD %>') === 'true') {
enableProdMode();
}

let BOOTSTRAP_PROVIDERS: any[] = [
DatabaseService,
provide(FIREBASE, { useValue: firebase })=======> Error cannot find module provide

];

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(WebModule, BOOTSTRAP_PROVIDERS);
```

*login.component.ts*

```
import { BaseComponent } from '../../frameworks/core/index';
import { DatabaseService } from '../../frameworks/demoapp/services/database.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

selector: 'demo-login',
templateUrl: 'path',
styleUrls: ['path']
})
export class LoginComponent {
 constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) {

 }
 login() {
 this.databaseService.authenticate(); =====> Edited
 }
 }
```

database.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { FIREBASE } from '../../demoapp/index';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {
private database: any;
private onSync: Function;
private userID: string;
constructor( @Inject(FIREBASE) firebase: any, private ngZone: NgZone)      
{
console.log('Constructing DatabaseService');
// Initialize Firebase
 var config = {
  // your web config from Firebase console
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
this.database = firebase.database();
}

public authenticate() {
                         ======>Edited
};
}
```

while giving database service inside constructor I couldn't load my app and got an error

> " No provider for Token firebase!"

How can I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
provide(FIREBASE, { useValue: firebase })=======> Error cannot find module provide
```

should be

```
{ provide: FIREBASE, useValue: firebase }
```

This syntax changed quite some time ago.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. provide issue solved. but  "No provider for Token firebase" not solved.

Comment: What code produces this error? Where do you inject `friebase`?

Comment: i attached my database.service.

Comment: I think you need to pass it to `bootstrap()` as `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(WebModule, {providers: BOOTSTRAP_PROVIDERS});`

Comment: i gave like that  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(WebModule, {providers: BOOTSTRAP_PROVIDERS}); but still not working

Comment: while loading login page getting the same error  " No provider for Token firebase!"

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look at github.com/jlooper/PocketRave you can see a complete Firebase integration using this seed

Comment: i follow that link too and edited my login.component.ts and database.service.ts. but  getting the error "this.databaseService.authenticate is not a function".